# scrypt 2.0.2 failing to build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, raspberry-pi, debian

`bundle install` of fat_free_crm needs gem "scrypt" version 2.0.2 (https://rubygems.org/gems/scrypt/versions/2.0.2) but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing scrypt:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/scrypt-2.0.2/ext/scrypt
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -rubygems /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.1/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/arm-linux/2.3.0/scrypt-2.0.2 RUBYLIBDIR=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/arm-linux/2.3.0/scrypt-2.0.2
mkdir -p arm-linux
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/fake_ffi -I../../lib/scrypt /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/exporter.rb ../../lib/scrypt/scrypt_ext.rb ./scrypt_ext.h
gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -msse -msse2 -fPIC   -o arm-linux/crypto_scrypt-sse.o -c ./crypto_scrypt-sse.c
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [gcc -fexceptions -O -fno-omit-frame-pointe...]
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/compile_task.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in define_task!'
Tasks: TOP => default => arm-linux/libscrypt_ext.so => arm-linux/crypto_scrypt-sse.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/scrypt-2.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/arm-linux/2.3.0/scrypt-2.0.2/gem_make.out
```

I can't find anything about this on the interwebs and I don't understand it myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume you are using an ARM device? Scrypt 2 has problems compiling on ARM: https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/issues/23

Comment: yes! It's a Raspberry Pi 3. I also noticed that the 3.0.x version compiled no problem but fat_free_crm depends on 2.0.2. Do you know if there is a way to use 3.0.2 in place of 2.0.2? Like, to tell the environment to use the 3.0.2 build whenever needing 2.0.2... I think I previously ran into this as a solution to a different program or gem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out**

```
sudo gem install rake
```

**Then install scrypt**

```
gem install scrypt
```